# Services to suggest changes in markup to improve search-engine friendliness (think W3Cs validation services)

Tags: validation, optimization, seo

Are there any services out there, that can parse a website and give some sort of feedback to how search-engine friendly that website is? And perhaps even suggest changes to the mark-up to improve indexing?

Think W3Cs validation services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Google Webmaster Tools](http://google.com/webmasters). After you add your site, it will often list "problems" with your site, such as duplicate title tags and meta descriptions, and also things like 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a [GoDaddy](http://godaddy.com) customer you can validate web-crawler friendliness on your hosted sites.

Answer (score 0):

Tools to automate alteration of markup code for any objective are a horribly frightful proposition.  Simply write your code correctly the first time.  If you have archaic code then it likely has many other problems in addition to SEO, and automatically imposing global changes can expose problems you may not be prepared to address.